# Term for a Prime k-tuple with no intermediate primes?

Tags: number-theory, terminology

Based upon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple, a k-tuple $T = (t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_k)$ is a Prime k-tuple if and only if there exists a non-empty set S such that all members of $\{ t_i + s \mid ( t_i \in T ) \land (s \in S)\}$ are prime. It also seems to be implied that $t_i < t_j \iff i < j$.

I wanted to know if there is a term for a more restrictive variety of Prime k-tuple such that not only is the above true, but also for any given $z \in S$ there does not exist a prime $p$ where $t_1 + z < p < t_k + z$ if and only if there is no $t_i \in T$ such that $t_i + z = p$?

For instance, for the Twin Prime k-tuple (0, 2) - there will never be a prime in between $p_n$ and $p_{n + 1} = p_n + 2$ (unless they make $1$ prime again).

And if there is no such term, what do you all think would be a good name for it? Minimal Prime k-tuple?